# Solid state relay (SSR) - alternating polarity

Tags: raspberry-pi, solid-state-relay, polarity

I'd like to control a slave clock, via a relay(s), which needs an alternating polarity pulse once a second.

The attached circuit incorporates two SPDT relays which do this (one relay activated one second, the other the next, to provide the alternating polarity).

I'd like to use a SSR relay though to avoid mechanical wear.

I've got some SPST DC-DC SSR relays but, as they're SPST, I can't see a way to replicate the circuit I've attached.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

[image: *Note: I can control the SPDT relays from a Raspberry Pi using a transistor circuit (output 5V). The SSR relays can be controlled using the output from the Pi without using a transistor (output 3 - 5V). The voltage the clock requires is around 24V DC.*]

Comment: If the load only needs 6V, there are plenty of other solutions... How much current does this "clock" need?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend an H-bridge driver.

If you've not familiar with them, they typically are implemented in a single IC or an IC with external power FETs, depending on the current you want. I don't know your load current but I'd guess it'll suit the former, a single IC.

Have a look at the ONSemi NCV7729 (5..28 V, 8 A) or ST L9958 (4..28 V, 8.6 A) to give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an H-Bridge circuit.

You can use four SPST-SS Relays as shown below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRaorl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

DO NOT press both buttons at once though. A centre off, momentary on left and right, toggle switch would be more appropriate.

However there are more "integrated" solutions for this.

Comment: Made me smile that you suggested relays after yesterday's solenoid exchange, with genuine warmth though. Hey, you don't have to shout "DO NOT" in capitals but you could spell 'once' properly. In little letters :-) :-)

Comment: @TonyM. I try to tailor my answers to the information in the question and not suggest alternatives that may be beyond the OPs skill level. OP stated he had a bunch of SPSTs so I answered it as is. Thanks for pointing out the other thing. Respect back at you. :)

Comment: Thank you Trevor - this is what I was looking for. I got the circuit working fine at first but now something odd's happened after I tidied up the wiring (all connections are fine though).

Everything's fine when RLY1 and 4 are on, but when RLY2 and 3 are on, there's a short circuit on the 9V load. Do you have any ideas why? Thanks!

Comment: @David They should operate 1&4 or 2&3. 1&3 should never be on at the same time. Also check your relays are all "Normally Open" type.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 2&3. I've just checked and the relays are the correct type.

Comment: @David, Re-check your wiring/joints then. You may also have a bad relay. Check they are all open circuit when nothing is pressed.

Comment: There seems to be a problem that when I operate relays 2 & 3, 1 & 4 also come on (I say they're "on" - their LEDs aren't lit but the voltage across the input terminals is about 3V). When 1 & 4 are operated independently, 2 & 3 stay off and everything's fine.

Comment: @David there has to be an issue with your wiring then. Or, it could be those SSRs need a drain resistor. I'll add to the schematic just in case. You can test that by shorting out the ones that are supposed to be off and see if the input stays at zero volts.

Comment: @David DO u have a part number for those SSRs?

Comment: I thought it was my wiring but I've carefully rewired it twice (with new wiring too). The strange thing is that I did get it working to begin with which makes me think one of the relays has malfunctioned for some reason. I'll look into the resistors though. They're Fotek SSR-25DD relays - I got them cheaply off eBay so I suspect they're the 'fake' ones but I believe they should still work (albeit at well below the 25 amps they're rated at!).

Comment: @David u try the test I mentioned above?

Comment: I'll try that now - possibly a stupid question here, but do I short the inputs or outputs of the relays that are supposed to be off?

Comment: @David, inputs. Also, what is that load you are switching? is it a coil of some sort?

Comment: @Trevor I tried the test - the inputs of the ones that are supposed to be off are about 3.5V, then drop to 0V when I short the inputs.

Comment: @David and the outputs turn off at that point?

Comment: Unfortunately the outputs seem to remain on as the short circuit is still present.

Comment: @David. What is that load you are switching? is it a coil of some sort?

Comment: Yes, it's the coil of a slave clock, but I've tried it with other loads too and get the same results. I don't know if this is significant, but the indicator LEDs on the two relays which are working properly are dimmer than the ones that seem to be playing up.

Comment: @David, sigh, then you are probably frying the SSRs because there is no fly-back path in there. See the diodes I added to the answer.